# Can I use joomla to build a portal on a website where

Tags: joomla, portal

I am new to web development

Can I use joomla to build a portal on a website where each client see information about their purchases

Comment: That question is kind of too broad. Basically you can use Joomla, but it is not a shopware, its a cms, so you have to use some component like virtuemart to do that. If you want create a serious webshop i would recommend magento, but that is totally different beast to tame…

Comment: Sorry I used the wrong construction of words, Its not an e-commerce website. The company i work renders advert services to clients. The purchases i meant was e.g Invoices, Billboards each campaigns are posted and the start and end date of the clients subscription

Comment: Well you can use joomla! for that… But it requires some coding…

Comment: how do you mean coding? php or html?

Comment: php, html, css — basically everything you need on top of the joomla framework.

Comment: okay, is there any other framework i could use, What would you recomend

Comment: Joomla! itself is also a framework for content management. I cannot tell which framework to choose, it depends on the requirements of your project.

Comment: This question might be better asked at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com